# After updating LiveData my switchMap don't want to trigger

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Like in title, I have _token

```
private val _token = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

that should update

```
val userPackages: LiveData<List<Packages>> = Transformations.switchMap(_token) {
        packagesLiveData(it)
    }
```

after i use

```
fun setToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setToken: $token")
        _token.postValue(token)
    }
```

from this Log.D I know that im getting valid string
i tried

```
_token.value = token
```

but nothing changed
I see from this function that im calling inside switchmap

```
private fun packagesLiveData(string: String): LiveData<List<Packages>> {
        Log.d(TAG, "switchMap: $string")
        return liveData {
            tvRepository
                .getUserPackage(string)
                .asLiveData()
        }
    }
```

that im not getting any change (cos this function not being called at all)
or if i inicialize value of _token to any string then i see it being called twice but with this initialized value and not with the value from _token.value that i confirmed while testing is indeed changing but switchmap can never access

**EDIT**

It looks like i just didn't observed my liveData but now when i try to do this I'm getting error that i don't have get function for this val
I'm getting my model in my fragment from this

```
private val tvViewModel: TvViewModel by viewModels()
```

and this is how my observer looks like

```
tvViewModel.userPackages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.d(TAG, "setTvObservers: ${it?.get(0)}")
        })
```

Requested ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TvViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tvRepository: TVRepository
) :
    ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "TvViewModel"
    }

    private val _tvPath = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val _token = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val tvPath: LiveData<String> = _tvPath

    val userPackages: LiveData<List<Packages>> = Transformations.switchMap(_token) {
        packagesLiveData(it)
    }

    fun setTvPath(path: String) {
        _tvPath.postValue(path)
    }

    fun setToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setToken: $token")
        _token.postValue(token)
    }

    private fun packagesLiveData(string: String): LiveData<List<Packages>> {
        Log.d(TAG, "switchMap: $string")
        return liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tvRepository
                .getUserPackage(string)
                .asLiveData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you `observing` this `LiveData`, i.e. `userPackages` somewhere?

Because as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations),

> The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is observing the returned LiveData object.

So make sure you are observing userPackages somewhere, if it still doesn't work do tell, we'll try to find a solution again :)

**EDIT:**

By looking at the way you were observing the `LiveData` using `viewLifecycleOwner`, it seems that you are observing it inside a `fragment`. So, inside a `fragment`, you do not get the `ViewModel` by calling `by viewModels()`. Instead, you need to use `by activityViewModels<TvViewModel>`

if it still doesn't work let me know, we'll try to look again :)

**LATEST UPDATE**

ok so even though this doesn't give any `compile-time` warnings, but inside your `packagesLiveData`, the `tvRepository.getUserPackage(string).asLiveData()` returns a `LiveData`, and you are using `livedata` wrapper again around it. What you need to do is something like this:

```
private fun packagesLiveData(string: String): LiveData<List<Packages>> {
    Log.d(TAG, "switchMap: $string")

    return tvRepository
            .getUserPackage(string)
            .asLiveData()
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and add code for your `ViewModel` as well :)

Comment: this is my view model, everything i provided is in my view model and this is almost all of it `No virtual method getUserPackages()Landroidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData; in class Lpl/beskidmedia/bm/tv/model/TvViewModel; or its super classes (declaration of 'pl.beskidmedia.bm.tv.model.TvViewModel' appears in /data/data/pl.beskidmedia.bm/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes15.dex)`
now when i registered observer for this i got this error

Comment: Where is your `ViewModel`? Can you edit your question and add code for it? :)

Comment: I edited my question, now u can see whole view model

Comment: ok, no error now but the switchmap still not being called

Comment: Ok wait, I figured it out, updating my answer

Comment: I'm afraid that i can't do this because i'm using suspend function and with this wrapper it was possible

Comment: then try removing the `.asLiveData()` at the end once and keep the outer `liveData(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: Ok, I found it, I had problem because I created multiple instances of the same viewModel, now switchMap gets called, unfortunately now i have different problem but I will create new question for this, thanks a lot for help and have a good day